# SQL, SELECT from two tables without getting all the rows

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables: `COMMENT` and `COMMENTHISTORY`

Now I need to SELECT cells from both tables, like this:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Userid, ch.Text, ch.Timestamp
FROM COMMENT c, COMMENTHISTORY ch
WHERE ch.CommentId = c.Id
ORDER BY ch.Timestamp DESC
```

Works fine. Only problem is that `COMMENTHISTORY` has several rows for each `COMMENT`, so the `SELECT` ends up retrieving several rows for each comment.

What I need is to retrieve one row for each comment. A row where the ch.Text and ch.Timestamp matches the latest relevant `COMMENTHISTORY` row.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I think inner join will help you.

Comment: try maxing the ch.Text and ch.Timestamp and group by the other two

Comment: SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL? Please modify the question to add the tag of the DB you are using

Comment: `COMMENTHISTORY` has row ID column?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT c.Id, 
       c.Userid, 
       ch.Text, 
       ch.Timestamp
FROM COMMENT c
INNER JOIN COMMENTHISTORY ch
  ON ch.CommentId = c.Id
WHERE ch.Timestamp = (SELECT MAX(ch2.Timestamp)
                      FROM COMMENTHISTORY ch2
                      WHERE ch2.CommentId = c.Id )
ORDER BY ch.Timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This will  fix your issue

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Userid, ch.Text, ch.Timestamp
FROM COMMENT c LEFT JOIN COMMENTHISTORY ch on C.ID = ch.comment_id
WHERE ch.CommentId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY ch.Timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Userid, ch.Text, max(ch.Timestamp)
FROM COMMENT c, COMMENTHISTORY ch
WHERE ch.CommentId = c.Id
GROUP BY C.ID, c.userid, ch.text
```

Comment: Will this work with `GROUP BY` not containing all the necessary columns except the one aggregated?

Comment: Is there any necessity of `ORDER BY` since you are taking the `MAX` of the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Userid, ch.Text, ch.Timestamp
FROM COMMENT c LEFT JOIN COMMENTHISTORY ch ON ch.CommentId = c.Id
ORDER BY ch.Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Doesn't work. This query gives exactly the same results as my own query (i.e. all the COMMENTHISTORY rows and not just the newest one)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Userid, Max(ch.Text), max(ch.Timestamp)
FROM COMMENT c, COMMENTHISTORY ch
WHERE ch.CommentId = c.Id
GROUP BY C.ID, c.Userid
ORDER BY ch.Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: `Max(ch.Text), max(ch.Timestamp)` may not return the same row

Comment: Column "COMMENTHISTORY.TimeStamp" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT c.Id, c.Userid, max(ch.Timestamp),max(ch.text)
    FROM COMMENT c, COMMENTHISTORY ch
    WHERE ch.CommentId = c.Id
    Group By  c.Id, c.Userid
    ORDER BY ch.Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: again `Max(ch.Text), max(ch.Timestamp)` may not return the same row

Answer (score 0):

This query will select last `CommentHisotry` record for latest record for given comment id:

```
WITH LastComment AS
(
    SELECT CH.CommentId, MAX(CH.Timestamp) as Date
    FROM COMMENTHISTORY CH
    GROUP BY CH.CommentId
)

SELECT c.Id, c.Userid, ch.Text, ch.Timestamp
FROM COMMENT c
INNER JOIN LastComment lc ON LC.CommentId = c.Id
INNER JOIN COMMENTHISTORY ch ON ch.CommentId = lc.CommentId and ch.TimeStamp = lc.Date
ORDER BY ch.Timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using inner join and put your conditions in Where clause . For more info please have a look of this :- [Joins selection diagram](http://peggysetareh.blogspot.in/2012/03/what-is-difference-between-inner-join.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  ch.CommentId, ch.Text, ch.TimeStamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY     ch.CommentId ORDER BY ch.TimeStamp DESC) RowNum
    FROM    COMMENTHISTORY ch
)
SELECT          c.Id, c.Userid, CTE.Text, CTE.TimeStamp
FROM            COMMENT c
    INNER JOIN  CTE ON c.Id = CTE.CommentId
WHERE           RowNum = 1
```